# Do session use cookies in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session

How can we make session, not use cookies ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default yes, the session will use cookies. To disable this, edit your `web.config`:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true"...
```